# SwiftUI: background of the last element in the VStack stretches out from the borders in case of Spacer usage

Tags: swiftui, background, vstack, safearea

I've just started learning of SwiftUI and I'm trying to make simple view:

```swift
var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 30) {
            Spacer()

            Text("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.")
            
            TextField("Some text", text: $model.trakingUrl) { val in
                
            }
                .textFieldStyle(PrimaryTextFieldStyle())
            Button {
                // code
            } label: {
                Text("Next")
                    .padding()
                    .background(Color.yellow)
            }
            .border(.black)
        }
    }
```

I want to align all elements to the bottom and it works

[image]
[image]

BUT as you can see the background of the button stretches out of the container and safearea. Without `Spacer()` it works but it gives wrong alignment. Adding some element after the Button also visually fixes this problem.

Please

1. Explain this behavior, why it happens?
2. How to fix it properly?

Version 14.2

Comment: Add fixed size to the button, vstacks are configured to fill in all the available space vertically

Comment: For a quick fix you can add `.padding(.bottom, 1)` to the Button